# SQL Query to compare the quarterly results for the top 5 salesperson

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have data with order amount for salesperson from 2003 Q3 to 2005 Q2, I would like to show the results of each quarter, salesperson and total order amount for top 5 salesperson.

I have this sql statement

```
select DATEPART (Year, [Order Date]) AS Year,
       DATEPART (QUARTER,[Order Date]) As Quarter, 
       Salesperson, 
       SUM([Order Amount]) As [Total Order Amount] 
from dbo.tbl_sales 
Group By DATEPART (YEAR, [Order Date]),  
         DATEPART (QUARTER, [Order Date]), 
         Salesperson 
Order By  SUM([Order Amount]) DESC
```

but it is not only showing the top 5 sales person, please help.

Comment: What is it showing ?

Comment: it is showing all the salesperon order amounts quarter by quarter.

Comment: Can provide a image of datalist where will mentioned that what you want and how data are showing

Comment: Hi Anik, sorry may I know how to attach the print screen here please?

Comment: You can't you don't have enough reputation. Upload the pic somewhere then paste the link here then will attach your pic with your question.

Comment: It should be like this in the result, thanks.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/wod0kl2uo35vdiu/printscreen.bmp?dl=0

Comment: This is part of the result from my SQL statement.   https://www.dropbox.com/s/pwnw2p1jo7t7dba/now.JPG?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want up to 5 per quarter. Try this:

```
select *
from (
    select
        T.Year, T.Quarter, T.Salesperson, T.[Total Order Amount],
        rank() over (partition by T.Year, T.Quarter order by T.[Total Order Amount] desc) as rnk
    from (
        select
            datepart(yy, [Order Date]) AS Year,
            datepart(qq,[Order Date]) As Quarter, 
            Salesperson, 
            sum([Order Amount]) As [Total Order Amount]
        from dbo.tbl_sales 
        group by
             datepart(yy, [Order Date]),  
             datepart(qq, [Order Date]), 
             Salesperson 
    ) as T
) as T2
where T2.rnk <= 5
order by T2.Year, T2.Quarter, T2.rnk, T2.Salesperson
```

I you want to rank the top 5 across all quarters and then breakout only those few then try this.

```
with top5 as (
    select Salesperson, rnk from (
        select Salesperson, rank() over (order by sum([Order Amount]) desc) as rnk
        from dbo.tbl_sales
        group by Salesperson
    ) as T
    where rnk <= 5
)
select
    datepart(yy, [Order Date]) as yr,
    datepart(qq, [Order Date]) as qtr, 
    s.Salesperson, 
    sum([Order Amount]) As [Quarterly Order Amount] 
from
    dbo.tbl_sales as s inner join
    top5 on top5.Salesperson = s.Salesperson
group by
    datepart(yy, [Order Date]),  
    datepart(qq, [Order Date]), 
    s.Salesperson 
order by
    yr,
    qtr
```

It helps to be a lot more explicit about what you need. As you can see those two queries are quite different. And after looking at the screenshots you posted I'm not sure that is the answer you're seeking.

Comment: Hi Shawnt00, may be I am confusing, I need to show the top 5 salespersons' order amount quarter by quarter. Thanks.

Comment: So you need to determine the two five by ranking them across all months and then break out only those five by quarter?

Comment: Firstly, I would need to find out the top five salesperson, I have done this by this sql statement   select TOP (5) Salesperson, SUM([Order Amount]) As [Total Order Amount] from dbo.tbl_sales Group by Salesperson Order By (SUM([Order Amount])) DESC  Then I need to find out the order amount quarter by quarter for these top 5 sales person

Comment: Hi Shawnt00, the second statement you wrote showed Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
Ambiguous column name 'Salesperson'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Ambiguous column name 'Salesperson'.

Comment: It's because there were two Salesperson columns available and I hadn't specified which one I meant.

Comment: Hi Shawnt00, I need to show the quarter first, then salesperson and total order amount. Thanks.

Comment: The output columns are listed in the same order as in your question. But that's a trivial charge regardless. I'm not sure what you're requesting.

Comment: Hi Shawnt00, it should show the same result as this https://www.dropbox.com/s/wod0kl2uo35vdiu/printscreen.bmp?dl=0 but it needs to show the quarter first, then salesperon, then total order amount, thanks.

Comment: You basically just repeated yourself. And I'm not sure how that description matches up with screenshot. Check out the pivot operation in SQL Server 2008 to get the year and quarter dimensions running across the columns. It won't work with a dynamic range of dates though.

Comment: Hi Shawnt00, the screenshot is made from excel, it does not need to be exactly the same format or dimension, only the data it shows need to be corrected and need to show quarter, salesperson then total order amount. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Shawnt00, I have this sql satement, but it only shows the total of quarter one but not quarter by quarter, please advise.    select Top (5) DATEPART (QUARTER,[Order Date]) As Quarter, Salesperson, SUM([Order Amount]) As [Total Order Amount] from dbo.tbl_sales Group By DATEPART (QUARTER,[Order Date]), Salesperson Order By DATEPART (QUARTER,[Order Date]), SUM([Order Amount]) DESC

Comment: I corrected the minor mistake from my query which ought to have been obvious to you as well. Have you even tried running it?

Comment: Hi Shawnt00, it shows Msg 8127, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
Column "top5.rnk" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. I am thinking if I can use subquery to tackle this. Thanks.

Comment: Another easy fix. It was a small stupid mistake for me to throw that in. I was just to help you see the data a little more clearly. All you needed to do was take that one line out.